# increasing font size in mobile settings make recyclerview items overlapping

Tags: android, xml

Recyclerview items are overlapping when I increase font size in settings.

in the first image recycler view items are normal but in the second image items are overlapping after increasing font size in settings.

[image]

[image]

this is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        style="@style/RecyclerviewArrowcolor"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:riv_oval="true"

        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewSupporter2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/itemImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diseasename"
        style="@style/Recyclerviewdiseasecolor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="disease name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewSupporter2"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diseasenickname"
        style="@style/Recyclerviewnicknamecolor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="disease nickname"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewSupporter2"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `itemImage` is only vertically constrained to the top and has a fixed height of 40 dp, the top TextView only has 20 dp of height to fit within (the space between the top of the card and your "view supporter"). When it wraps to two lines, it stays centered in that 20 dp space and spills out to cover things above/below it.

You should rethink how you are setting up these constraints so they will be flexible with respect to font size changes causing more lines of text. For example, you could make the image be centered vertically in the row by constraining it to both the top and bottom like this, and get rid of the "ViewSupporter" entirely

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            style="@style/RecyclerviewArrowcolor"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:riv_oval="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diseasename"
            style="@style/Recyclerviewdiseasecolor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="disease name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diseasenickname"
            style="@style/Recyclerviewnicknamecolor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="disease nickname"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/diseasename"
            tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

If you wanted to keep the image centered on the line between the two TextViews, you could do that too by adjusting the image top and bottom constraints

```xml
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
    style="@style/RecyclerviewArrowcolor"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/diseasename"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/diseasenickname"
    app:riv_oval="true"/>
```